# Express, Wildcard-Subdomains, and sendFile()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, wildcard-subdomain

I'm using [Wildcard Subdomains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wildcard-subdomains) on my Express server so that when users go to `name.example.com`, or request something from the API from that subdomain it all works well.  (Navigating to `name.example.com/api` works correctly)

However, actually navigating to `name.example.com` needs to serve an `index.html` file; I'm using the code below as a catchall, but any files that are linked to inside the HTML file (like a stylesheet or JS file) are being served with the contents of `index.html`.

```
// routes/routefile.js
router.get('/_sub/:name/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
});
```

My file structure:

```
Project/
|_ routes/
|_ public/
|_ server.js
```

If there's a better package I should be using, please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This works:

`app.use('/_sub/:name/', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/')));`